# Why Ansible ignores ansible_become_password variable?

Tags: sudo, ansible

I am provisioning a VM via local connection with Ansible. Some tasks require su privileges (to be granted via sudo).

I can't use the --ask-become-password switch as I want the provisioning to be completely automated.

Here is my playbook play.yml:

```
---
  - hosts: all
    gather_facts: yes
    roles:
      - role1
```

Here is roles/role1/tasks/main.yml:

```
---
  - name: Update apt-get cache (apt-get update)
    become: true
    apt: update_cache=yes
```

My inventory:

```
localhost
```

Finally host_vars/localhost.yml:

```
---
ansible_connection: local
ansible_become_pass: user
```

I get the following error while running the playbook with: `ansible-playbook -i inventory play.yml -vvvv`

```
<localhost> REMOTE_MODULE apt update_cache=yes
<localhost> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'mkdir -p /tmp/ansible-tmp-1448910759.16-277915614747763 && chmod a+rx /tmp/ansible-tmp-1448910759.16-277915614747763 && echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1448910759.16-277915614747763']
<localhost> PUT /tmp/tmpKuhTO2 TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1448910759.16-277915614747763/apt
<localhost> EXEC ['/bin/sh', '-c', u'chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1448910759.16-277915614747763/apt']
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=ilkbtrjkxxznhmgwvdaglfojzolhhfhz] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ilkbtrjkxxznhmgwvdaglfojzolhhfhz; LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1448910759.16-277915614747763/apt'"'"''
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=stcxercjkjtxgyzjewlffytjjwcwidip] password: " -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-stcxercjkjtxgyzjewlffytjjwcwidip; LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C /usr/bin/python /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1449081640.46-119933765060267/apt; rm -rf /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1449081640.46-119933765060267/ >/dev/null 2>&1'"'"''
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
[sudo via ansible, key=stcxercjkjtxgyzjewlffytjjwcwidip] password:
```

Why ansible_become_password for localhost is being ignored?

I have noticed that the password is not being reported in Ansible verbose output, but I don't know if it's the default behavior.

Ansible 1.9.4, default ansible.cfg on Ubuntu Server 15.10.

EDIT: updated playbooks (removed `ansible_become_user` variable) and output.

**the play works if I run it with the `--ask-become-password` switch.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ansible_become_user` is used to [switch to a user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) much like `su`.

If that user doesn't have the right privileges to perform the task without further privilege escalation then the task will fail.

If you remove your `ansible_become_user` line it will default to root which should then be able to do anything.

Comment: If the user needs to sudo then it doesn't have the right privileges and instead is needing to escalate (this is what sudo does). You can't chain privilege escalation (as far as I know) in Ansible so either use `ansible_become_user` to a properly privileged user (such as root or any other user with the right privileges for the operation you are trying to do) or remove it entirely to have it default to root.

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing `ansible_become_user` but it's not working

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) says to use `ansible_become_pass`, and not `ansible_become_password`.

> ansible_become
>   equivalent to ansible_sudo or ansible_su, allows to force privilege escalation
>
> ansible_become_method
>   allows to set privilege escalation method
>
> ansible_become_user
>   equivalent to ansible_sudo_user or ansible_su_user, allows to set the user you become through privilege escalation
>
> ansible_become_pass
>   equivalent to ansible_sudo_pass or ansible_su_pass, allows you to set the privilege escalation password

Comment: ansible_become_password is an alias for ansible_become_pass, see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/dc0fae1af76821ab6fb741cd3e9da285a9d815a2/lib/ansible/playbook/play_context.py#L64

Comment: Those docs are a little vague.. "ansible_become_pass = False" will stop Ansible from sending a blank password... which you won't want if you've got the user in the wheel group with NOPASSWD: ALL.